# PHP+Cookies: Show message once only

Tags: php, cookies

I'm having a problem with this really short piece of code which I cannot get to work.

Basically, I want to display two different messages, depending on whether the user is new or returning.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_COOKIE['visit']) && ($_COOKIE['visit'] == "true")) 
{ 
  echo 'cookie set, welcome back';
}else{ 
  echo 'cookie not set, welcome new user';
} 
setcookie("visit", "true", time()+60*60*24*600); 
?>
```

The problem is that the cookie is not being set. I don't know what is wrong, can anyone help me?

Comment: What happens? Have you checked in your browser that the cookie gets sent?

Comment: You likely don't need to be calling `setcookie()` on every request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move the setcookie into the condition:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_COOKIE['visit']) && $_COOKIE['visit'] == "true"){
    echo 'cookie set, welcome back';
}else{
    echo 'cookie not set, welcome new user';
    setcookie("visit", "true", time()+60*60*24*600);
}
?>
```

If its not working then you should check the cookie is being sent back to the script. eg your browser or some browser addon interfering.

Be aware there is a new law that if your server is based in the EU, it requires you to obtain informed consent from your visitors before you can store or retrieve **any** information on there computer. http://www.cookielaw.org/

Comment: Thanks for response! The script itself appears to be working actually, but the cookie is only being set if the user engages in another action where another cookie is being set (e.g. login, in my case). So, the cookie is only being set in combination with another cookie... weird

Answer (score 0):

I had used the above code to make a modal window show only once.

The problem with the above is I was trying to use it at the end of a index page you can only use setcookie at the point where headers are set.

Instead I used:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['visit']) && $_COOKIE['visit'] == "true"){
    $load = false;
} else {
    $load = true;
    setcookie("visit", "true", time()+60*60*24*600);
}
```

That sets the cookie at the top of my PHP file if its not set then I use

```
if($load == true){
    //do code on first run
}
```

where I needed to add code for the single run, I used it in the head to set a css style sheet for the one time use and in the footer to set some script / html for the one time use.